# What do you call this thick washer-type part?

Tags: hardware, guide

I have been going through many parts that I have recently gotten ahold of. However, I don't know what many are or what they do. I ran into this **steel** part:

[image]

It is 0.565 in tall, with an inner diameter of 0.25 in and an outer diameter of 1.25 in.

I'm not sure if it is a thick spacer, a tall washer, or something entirely different.

Does anyone know exactly what it is or what it is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a [bushing, or "plain bearing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushing_%28bearing%29#Bushing).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a brass spacer to me:

[image]

Though it could be some sort of brass (or steel, as indicated by the asker) roller like you might find in something like a laser printer (if they still used metal parts in laser printers instead of plastic).

I think it would be impossible to say with any certainty exactly what it's meant for without seeing where it came from.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the part is made of steel.

Comment: I bought a towing hitch receiver a while back.  It looks like one of the spacers that was provided with the install kit.  The spacer was used to bridge the difference between the flat receiver frame and the angled truck frame.

Comment: I updated my answer to include steel, but the material doesn't really change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Johnny has stated the top photo appears to be a spacer made of a nonferrous material or plated. The bottom photo shows what is commonly called a fender washer. A fender washer has an outside diameter larger than a standard washer of the same inside diameter. The larger size allows it spread the clamping load over a larger surface preventing damage to the surface of the pieces being bolted together.

Comment: I forgot to mention the part is made out of steel. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a spacer/ bushing. I am searching for a similar one to allow a part to rotate freely inside the outer diameter of this spacer. Instead of the part being pressed by the bolt, the bolt presses on this spacer. The part is slid on to this spacer prior to getting the bolt through. The part should be thinner in height than the spacer to allow rotation.